# Keeping lines to less than 80 characters

Tags: line-breaks

The code standard that I use indicates that lines should have less than 80 chars. I want to indicate this automatically while I write to avoid raising the error later.

What is a good way of showing it?

Comment: @JoshPetrie Not a duplicate, in my opinion.  This question is more general because there are other ways to indicate the lines are too long. (See the `gitcommit` syntax, for example, which uses syntax highlighting.)

Answer (score 35):

If you have Vim 7.3 or later, you can set `colorcolumn`, or `cc`.

```
:set colorcolumn=80
```

From [`:help colorcolumn`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'colorcolumn'):

> 'colorcolumn' is a comma separated list of screen columns that are
>   highlighted with ColorColumn hl-ColorColumn. Useful to align text.

You can also set it relative to your `textwidth` variable, which is maybe more
useful than setting it to an absolute value:

```
:set colorcolumn=+1
```

Or set multiple columns:

```
:set colorcolumn=-1,+30
```

To change the color of the `colorcolumn` use `:highlight ColorColumn`, for
example:

```
:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the colorcolumn option, you can tell vim to automatically push you down to the next line by putting:

```
set textwidth=80
```

into your .vimrc file.

From the docs (`:h textwidth`)

> Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
>   broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
>   this.  'textwidth' is set to 0 when the 'paste' option is set.  When
>   'textwidth' is zero, 'wrapmargin' may be used.  See also
>   'formatoptions' and ins-textwidth.
>
> When 'formatexpr' is set it will be used to break the line.
>
> NOTE: This option is set to 0 when 'compatible' is set.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of showing a line showing the maximum size, the extra characters can also been highlighted through

`:let w:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)`

This will set the extra characters to be marked as error (normally, red background, but it depends on the color scheme).

This can be added to `.vimrc` to do it automatically on each file

`:au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)`

Comment: Where can I find documentation for the w:m1 and w:m2 variables?