# how to break a long line into 80 characters per line

Tags: line-breaks

[image: long line]

my .vimrc setting for wrapping line:

```
set nowrap " Don't auto wrap on load
set fo-=t " Don't wrap text when type
"set colorcolumn= 80
```

Comment: `set wrap` and `set textwidth=80` should do it. You can control Vim wrapping pretty precisely see [`:h 'wrap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27), [`:h 'textwidth'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27) and have a look at [`:h 'linebreak'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27linebreak%27)

Comment: And of course `gq` to format long lines according to your textwidth setting

Answer (score 1):

Use `:set tw=80`. Also make sure you are not in “paste” mode. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272371/4752883)

If you need visual guidance on where you are with respect to 80 characters you can use `:set colorcolumn = 80` (https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/576/13848)